# Multi Phrase / Word Autocompletebox for Silverlight

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-4.0, autocomplete, silverlight-toolkit, autosuggest

I have been using the [autocompletebox from Silverlight Toolkit](http://jesseliberty.com/2011/07/25/windows-phone-toolkit-autocompletebox/) for Windows Phone.

What kind of changes (changes/extended ?) will be needed to enable the autocompletebox
to support auto completion for multiple phrases/words ? i.e. support something similar to

### [image: Enabling autosuggest for the 2nd word also?]

as soon as 'c' is entered in above the dropdown list shows items starting with 'c' etc.

(or how can this be achieved using normal text box?)

Related to this
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/180311/Rich-Text-Box-With-Intellisense-Ability

Answer (score 2):

I found this article useful..

Using (and customizing) the AutoCompleteBox for Windows Phone

http://www.croitoriu.com/blog/2012/02/using-and-customizing-the-autocompletebox-for-windows-phone/

[image: data source]

[image: autocomplete]